# EasyAdminBundle: error add entity with a composite primary key

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I have a Vehicule entity which I want to configure it with **easyAdmin Bundle**.
my entity has two primary keys: **immatriculation and user(from entity users : id_user)**:

```
 //Vehicule Entity
 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="num_immat")
 */
private $immatriculation;
 /** 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CMN\PortailFretBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="vehicules")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id_user")
 */
private $user;
```

I added my entity to the admin.yml file:

```
entities:
    Vehicule:
        label: "vehicules"
        class: CMN\PortailFretBundle\Entity\Vehicule
        form:
            fields: ['immatriculation','longueur', 'user']
        edit:
            fields: ['immatriculation','longueur', 'user']
        list:
            fields:
                 - { property: 'immatriculation'}
                 - { property: 'longueur'}
```

When I try to see the Vehicule management I get this error:

```
Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity CMN\PortailFretBundle\Entity\Vehicule
```

Does the easyAdminBundle doesn't support two primary keys ?? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found in the [documentation](https://github.com/npotier/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/README.md) that composite keys are not supported.